# Excel - Prevent Duplicates in column

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

Using the "Data Validation" option, i have been able to prevent the duplicate entry in the column. But i want an option to display the data available in the next column of the already existing entry along with the error message. 
For example, I have a 2 column worksheet with column A having Account Number and column B having Name. I have put a data validation check on Column A to prevent duplicate account number using =COUNTIF($range,firstcellinrange) = 1. In the Error Alert, It currently gives me a user defined error message. But i wish to display the "Name" (Column B) in the error alert pertaining to the account number already available in the worksheet.

Comment: Data validation error message is inbuilt and cannot be hacked like you want. You would have to use VBA to get this done.

Comment: Can you help me with a VBA for duplicate check + error message customisation.

Comment: It sounds like if we were to give you VBA code you wouldn't understand it. I suggest you try to find and understand a solution using VBA and come back here and edit your answer with what you've tried if you can't get it to work.